# How can I use pass as credentials helper for Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

In git I can use `pass` as a credential helper [^1](https://www.passwordstore.org).

```
[credential "https://github.com"]
    helper = !pass git/rlue@github
```

Can I set up Mercurial/hg to also delegate password management to the `pass` tool?

Comment: I removed the new tag [pass]. The word is far too generic for a tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You can't

**Longer answer**

Mercurial has not concept of Git's credential helpers, but

a) because credentials may be needed only for pull|push, you can try (somehow) to emulate helpers with pre-* hooks, which just call pass (AFAICS, pass with filename without options just show file-content and nothing more)

b) Mercurial has such thing as [Keyring Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension)

> uses services of the keyring library to securely save authentication passwords

and [keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/#third-party-backends), in turn, can support

> additional keyring backend implementations available for other use cases

I.e. if you'll find|write backend for keyring, which will support pass directly or pass files, you can try to use Keyring Extension with new backend in "credential helper way"

PS: The latter thought is published on the rights of a dirty crazy idea, not a tested and|or *at least* implementable solution